# JPA/Hibernate: Can you create a join query on an specific MapKey?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I wanted to test a query with a join on a Map attribute for one specific MapKey entry and I could not yet find a solution. Did anyone ever accomplish such a query and could share the correct JPQL / HQL?

The MapKey column is an `enum` type and the value is another `@Entity`.

This is the model:

```
@Entity
public class Operation {

    @Id
    private int id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operation", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Map<OperationDetailsType, OperationDetails> operationDetails;
}

@Entity
public class OperationDetails {

    @Id
    private int id;

    private String details;

}

public enum OperationDetailsType { SHORT, FULL }
```

This is the query I have currently tried:

```
SELECT operation FROM Operation operation join operation.operationDetails['SHORT'] operationDetailsShort WHERE operationDetailsShort.details = :el1
```

I have found this reference in the Hibernate Community, but the approach with `[...]` raises an error:
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1004884

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: [ near line 1,...
```

Hibernate Version is : 4.3.8.Final

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After changing the approach of searching the net I finally found a working solution.

The point is to use a `JOIN ... ON key()` query.

Here's the query syntax to get this JPA query running:

```
SELECT operation FROM Operation operation
    JOIN operation.operationDetails operationDetailsShort ON key(operationDetailsShort) = 'SHORT'
  WHERE operationDetailsShort.details = :el1
```

The nice thing about this construct is that you can create queries against both `OperationDetails` for specific `details`: (Without saying that this is a performant solution)

```
SELECT operation FROM Operation operation
    JOIN operation.operationDetails operationDetailsShort ON key(operationDetailsShort) = 'SHORT'
    JOIN operation.operationDetails operationDetailsLong ON key(operationDetailsFull) = 'FULL'
  WHERE operationDetailsShort.details = :el1
    AND operationDetailsFull.details = :el2
```

EDIT: As Vlad Mihalcea mentioned, the JPQL equivalent of hibernaes `JOIN ... WITH` is `JOIN ... ON`. I can confirm that this worked too and have updated the querys.

Comment: One observation only. The WITH is an HQL keyword. The JPQL equivalent is ON, which translates to a ON JOIN condition in the resulting SQL.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I will try it and update the answer if that works too

Comment: You are welcome. ON was added to [JPA 2.1](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-21-overview/) so it's worth mentioning it too.